# Hibernate catching how to implement?

Tags: hibernate

I tried to implement catching in hibernate in eclipse IDE. I am not getting any idea to implement it please anybody help me to implement catching in hibernate.

Comment: Do you mean "caching" or really "catching?"

Answer (score 0):

Well in Hibernate, caching are of 2 types

1.1st Level Cache:

1st Level of Caching is by default and is on the Session Level meaning each Session will behave as a first level Cache and store objects in it .

2. 2nd Level Cache:

2nd Level Cache is basically on the Session Factory Level meaning for the entire Application. For implementing 2nd level Cache, you have to make use of third party API`s such as Ehcache, Swarm Cache, Tree Cache etc.

Hope this helps